# Trilogy of books set in the future with "knights", "priests", and dwarfs and a rebellion

Tags: story-identification, religion

In the 80s, I was introduced to a sci-fi/fantasy trilogy of books. The books were set in the future. There were "knights", "priests", and dwarfs. The dwarfs were help for the knights. As the books evolved, the churches that the commoners were "controlled" by and went to used technology claimed by the priests to be divine power, but it was revealed as the books developed that the  making of sounds and visuals in church was technology of the past that was hidden from the commoners but used to convince them that the "priests" had powers. What the priests were using was tape players and projectors. I kind of remember the main character was a young man who became a knight, but rebelled against the control of the workers/commoners by the religion's "priests".

I read these books in the early to mid 80s. If anyone has a memory or any thought to what these 3 books are, let me know.

Comment: Do you mean "dwarves" or "dwarfs"? The former is the fantasy race. The latter are disproportionately small humans.

Comment: @SeanDuggan The spelling "dwarves" was invented by Tolkien, and there were mythical "dwarfs" before his time.

Comment: Fair enough. Common usage that I've seen, though, distinguishes the two.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Looks like Jason has cleared this up: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103179/why-is-it-dwarves-and-not-dwarfs

Comment: see OP confirmation comment for answer below

Answer (score 6):

This sounds very much like John Christopher's [Sword of the Spirits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_the_Spirits) trilogy, published in the early 70s.

They're set in a post-apocalyptic future society in which the Seers are in charge of spiritual matters, condemning all technology as evil. It later turns out that **the 'miracles' performed by the Seers are in fact due to technology** they secretly possess and which they plan to return to the world. **The main character is a young man, originally a commoner, later the Prince's son**, later still recruited by the Seers to be the Prince of Princes, **overthrow the current system**, and return technology to the world. There were **small and often deformed people** (I think it was hinted that they were born due to radiation after a nuclear disaster), **who acted as servants** to the 'normal' humans, and also some similarly small people who may have been called **'dwarves'** and were respected as smiths.

(Apologies for my vagueness: I only read the first book, and it was some years ago.)

Comment: youre a legend rand al'thor thats exactly the premise of the books. im sure pretty sure thats the title too.well now i got to see if i can track the books down.thanks

Comment: @deltron001 Happy to help! I've been trying to track down the 2nd and 3rd in the series for ages too. And if you come back to this page, please remember to click the green tickmark to the left of my answer to show that it's the correct one! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - at Amazon you can find [The Prince In Waiting](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1481419919?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01), [Beyond The Burning Lands](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1481419943?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01), and [The Sword Of The Spirits](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1481419978?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00).